# T-rex tile server with PostGIS (Windows) : utf-8 encoding error

Tags: postgis, vector-tiles, utf-8

I want to use T-rex as vector tileserver on Windows.
I load osm.pbf file (from geofabrik) to PostGIS database with osm2pgsql successfully.

When I run the server with the following commands, I get the error message :

- Command :

*t_rex serve --dbconn postgresql://Myuser:Mypass@localhost/Mydb*

- Error :

*ERROR IO error: invalid utf-8 sequence of 1 bytes from index 34*

Even when I just want to generate the config file, same error :

*t_rex genconfig --dbconn postgresql://Myuser:Mypass@localhost/Mydb*

I suspect this is a postgis setup problem ... that may not have anything to do with T-rex?
Unless it is an import configuration problem?

Note that using T-rex directly with a pbf file does not pose this problem (*t_rex serve --datasource My.osm.pbf*).

Comment: what encoding is your database in? (see [this answer on how to find this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6454215/5158630)). I'd expect osm2pgsql to create it in utf8 but if it's in something like latin-1 that might be the problem

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, the database is well encoded in utf8 (command SHOW SERVER_ENCODING)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following

```
SELECT pg_encoding_to_char(encoding), datname FROM pg_database order by datname;
```

That should show the per-database encodings. The **SHOW SERVER_ENCODING** that I suggested seems to show the default encoding, but import tools are free to choose a different encoding when they create a database

I think I've seen encoding issues before using shp2pgsql, but not osm2pgsql.

If your database still shows up as utf-8, i'd suggest raising an issue on the github page

Comment: hi,
thank you for your proposal. This command confirms me that the data is in utf8.
I loaded the same data using osmosis. The schema of the database obtained is different, but with t-rex I no longer have this error message (I have other problems because the map does not appear, but it is not the object of this exchange).

Comment: no problem! i'm a bit puzzled as osm2pgsql appears to correctly set the  encoding on the database. perhaps its some genuine data glitch which osmosis cleans up to t_rex's satisfaction, but osm2pgsql doesn't.